# Need help joining an Oracle database to SQL Server database when the case sensitivity does not match

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join

I do not have write access to these databases and am not looking to change the entire database's collation. However, I need to join the oracle columns Name and Date to the Sql Server column Name and Date. When I attempt to do them in Tableau, I get a collation error for the Name.

1. Oracle table contains columns::

   - 'Name' (ANSI/MCBS character string) (sort flag = Case-sensitive)
   - 'Date' (datetime)
   - 'Location' (ANSI/MCBS character string)  (sort flag = Case-sensitive)
2. Sql Server table contains columns:

   - 'Name' (Unicode character string) (sort flag = Case-insensitive)
   - 'Date' (datetime)
   - 'Sale_Type' (Unicode character string) (sort flag = Case-insensitive)

I tried turning the column 'Name' in Oracle to `UNISTR(Name)` and it did change the character string to Unicode character string. However, the sort flags between the two do not match and it still brings a collation error. SQL Server collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and I tried `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` and it did not change the sort to Case Sensitive.

```
select UNISTR(name) as Name,
Date,
Location
from oracle

select Name,
Date,
Sale_Type
from Sql_Server
```

I want to be able to join the Name between Oracle and SQL Server without any collation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I can not advise with oracle, but with SQL Server you can change collation during run time. In case if the underlying SQL data source is `view`, you can change the collation within `view` definition as follows (use may want to use exact collation that been mentioned in error message to avoid the error):

```
select Name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS as Name_CS,
Date,
Sale_Type
from Sql_Server
```

Comment: I tried this but the sort flag is still listed as case-insensitive. Would an alter session work in this case? I'm not too familiar with what that would do and do not want to unintentionally impact the database.

Comment: Hi @Raymond, do you (alter session) mean altering database to change collation? if so, that would not make any difference, in other words DO NOT change as it interrupts the application of that particular database. when you say _still listed as case-insensitive_ does it show in error message? what exactly error says, can you pls post error message part of your question, so that it make everyone better understanding of scenario

Answer (score 0):

When querying across DB link between Oracle and SQL Server you will need to match all upper/lower casing and column names may need to be wrapped in double quotes.